# Having trouble rendering a React element passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following component:

```
const Chip = (props) => {
  const ChipIcon = props.icon;
  let deleteButton = null;

  if (!props.readOnly) {
    deleteButton = <Delete
      style={styles.deleteButton}
      onTouchTap={props.onRemove}
    />
  }

  return <div className="Chip" style={styles.tag}>
    <ChipIcon />
    {' ' + props.label + ' '}
    {deleteButton}
  </div>
};
```

`props.icon` is definitely a Material UI `SvgIcon`, yet I get warnings when I try this.

> arning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Chip`.

But this seems to work:

```
const Chip = (props) => {
  const chipIcon = props.icon;
  let deleteButton = null;

  if (!props.readOnly) {
    deleteButton = <Delete
      style={styles.deleteButton}
      onTouchTap={props.onRemove}
    />
  }

  return <div className="Chip" style={styles.tag}>
    {chipIcon}
    {' ' + props.label + ' '}
    {deleteButton}
  </div>
};
```

Why doesn't the first one work, if it's truly a React element?

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around the returned value? Maybe something is going wrong as JS thinks the return statement is finished after the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `icon` property is already the element, and not the class that you use to render the element.

In JSX `<ChipIcon />` would be transformed to `React.createElement(ChipIcon, null)`. Your `icon` property is **already** the created element, not the class you pass to React to create the element for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example would work if `ChipIcon` was a React *component*. Your second example works, because `chipIcon` is a React *element*, i.e. already rendered component.

You can instantiate a component using jsx syntax this way: `<MyComponent />` if `MyComponent` is a React component. If `MyComponent` is already a rendered component, you inject it using the syntax `{ MyComponent }` as it already is a valid element. But is doesn't make much sense to use a rendered *element* as a component class : `<MyComponent />` really is `React.createElement(MyComponent, null)`.